# UTF-8 escape sequence as string: surely a better way

Tags: c#, string, encoding, utf-8

Reviewing some old code of mine, and wondered if there was a better way to create a literal string with unicode symbols...

I have a REST interface that requires certain escaped characters; for example, a property called username with value of john%foobar+Smith that must be requested like this:

```
{"username":"john\u0025foobar\u002bSmith"}
```

My c# method to replace certain characters like % and + is pretty basic:

```
public static string EncodeUTF8(string unescaped) {
    string utf8_ampersand = @"\u0026";
    string utf8_percent = @"\u0025";
    string utf8_plus = @"\u002b";
    return unescaped.Replace("&", utf8_ampersand).Replace("+", utf8_plus).Replace("%", utf8_percent);
}
```

This seems an antiquated way to do this; surely there is some single line method using Encoding that would output literal UTF code, but I can't find any examples that aren't essentially replace statements like mine... is there a better way?

Comment: There is nothing about UTF8 in this question. It is Unicode.

Comment: Don't do that.  You should use a JSON serializer.

Comment: @SLaks You don't need to escape + and % in JSON

Comment: It's a limitation of the back-end web service, I know json doesn't ordinarily need to be escaped like this.

Comment: @brnwdrng You could use a regex with a replacer method, but I don't think it would be a big win.

Comment: Yeah, I agree, it would just be a slightly condensed version of what I have already.  I was hoping there was some kind of method like EncodeUnicode("john%smith", "%") that would return "john\u0025smith", but it may be wishful thinking - couldn't find anything like that in MSDN

Comment: Who's responsible for the web service? This behaviour is just broken... you should at least *try* to get the web service fixed.

Comment: A client... no idea why their Oracle-driven secure web service doesn't tolerate these three characters - an unfortunate hack, may revisit subject with them on a day when I'm feeling extra patient.

Comment: Turns out the + symbol does not cause problems, it is just the % and & symbols, and they produce different error codes:

`{"name":"foo+bar"} >> {"status":"ok"}
Status Code: 200
Server: Oracle XML DB/Oracle Database
Content-Length: 15
Content-Type: application/json`


{"name":"foo%bar"}
Status Code: 403 Forbidden
Server: Oracle XML DB/Oracle Database
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8


`{"name":"foo&bar"}
Status Code: 400 Bad Request
Server: Oracle XML DB/Oracle Database
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8`

Comment: Sorry not sure how to put carriage returns in comments

Comment: @JonSkeet Figured it out - you'll never believe it though. They take every POST and rewrite it as a parameter-ized GET, then execute that. So, % and & being url delimiters, my POST json data gets turned into ~/services/methodName?package={%22name%22:%22foo&bar%22}, and fails due to being improperly formatted url strings.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it with Regex:

```
static readonly Regex ReplacerRegex = new Regex("[&+%]");

public static string Replace(Match match)
{
    // 4-digits hex of the matched char
    return @"\u" + ((int)match.Value[0]).ToString("x4");
}

public static string EncodeUTF8(string unescaped)
{
    return ReplacerRegex.Replace(unescaped, Replace);
}
```

But **i don't suggest it very much** (unless you have tens of replaces). I do think it would be slower, and bigger to write.

Comment: Yeah that's more handsome code, but I agree it's overkill; my version is easier to interpret at a glance, was just hoping a slicker native method had arrived in the three years since I wrote it - guess not - but thanks!

Comment: @brnwdrng The only advantage is if you have tens of characters to replace: the unicode code is automatically calculated, so you don't have to write it and risk writing it wrong.

Comment: Another advantage of this approach (assuming you'd use dictionary to map match to replacement instead of `String.Format`) that it allows replacing characters with different values in one pass.

Comment: Right; I do have a couple of service requests that might conceivably have 10's of replacements... this would appear safer.